# Databound List to Pivot

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have an object which has a List in it's properties, I would like each item in that list to appear on it's own page in the pivot.

Is a list a valid object to do this with, and how do I start?

Do I have to implement an interface in the object or do something in the pivot page code to implement cycling through the list items?

Comment: does your list load async? or is it ready to use in constructor?

Comment: the object is loaded fully from an xml file first. i just want to cycle through next and previous using the pivot control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the ItemSource of the Pivot control, and then change it's ItemTemplate to customize the view.

However, I would advice against it, if you have more than 7 items in the list, since this is the de-facto recommended maximum of pivot items.

Example:

```
<controls:Pivot ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
   <control:Pivot.HeaderrTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <!-- the pivot header -->
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding HeaderProperty}" />
       </DataTemplate>
   <control:Pivot.HeaderTemplate>
   <control:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <Grid>
               <!-- your template here -->
           </Grid>
       </DataTemplate>
   <control:Pivot.ItemTemplate>
</controls>
```

Comment: I will have up to 40 items. would you recommend i use transition effects rather than use pivot controls?

Comment: What kind of items are you intending to display? The thing is that the pivot headers aren't virtualized, so you would be rendering 40 headers (the content is of course virtualized), so it could feel very laggy for the user.

Comment: The items are Questions with a title, a body and a further List of possible answers, and one of those has a bool flag of true.

Comment: So a kind of wizard/quiz. It's not awful much content. You could try out the pivot and see if it works out. But if it uses to much memory, or lags to much, you should use custom transitions instead, and update the content.

Comment: Whatever suits you? You want a enumerable (typically ObservableCollection<T>) of your items, where each item have a header, and the remaining properties for the data you wish to display.

Comment: Woo woo woo! 40 items in a pivot = massive performance issues. 7 is the maximum recommended number. The pivot is also not designed for this type of wizard like usage.